# TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python

These are the codes for my classes:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

class Salary:
    def jump(self, name, salary):
        print(self.name, self.salary)


class Male(Salary, Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, gender, occupation):
        super(Male, self).__init__(name, gender, occupation)
        self.occupation = occupation

# Separate from all classes (list of instantiated objects)
employee1 = Male("Jim", "male", "technician")
print(Male.name)
```

When I use the last two lines of the code after creating all my classes, a `TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given` error occurs referencing the `super(Male, self).`... and `employee1 = Male(`... lines.

Comment: `super(Dog, self).__init__(name, color, owner)` has one too many arguments

Comment: Extra, `k = Klass()` and `k.method()` means exactly same to `Klass.method(k)`.

Comment: You are using inheritance wrong; a `Male` is not a kind of `Salary`.

Comment: You are also using `super` wrong; you have to be aware of what classes appear in the method resolution order of `Male`, so that you don't pass any arguments that won't be expected. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for more information on using `super` correctly.

Comment: What's the question? Is the problem not obvious? None of the parent classes take `occupation`, so why are you passing it to `super().__init__()`?

Comment: You probably meant `employee1.name` instead of `Male.name`

Comment: You totally changed the names in your code after some comments and answers were posted, though the functionality is mostly the same. Please don't do that; it's confusing at best, and rude at worst since it's like you're nullifying people's hard work.

Answer (score 9):

Under Pet you have:

```
def __init__(self, name, color):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
```

Under Dog you have:

```
def __init__(self, name, color, owner):
    super(Dog, self).__init__(name, color, owner)
```

Under Dog there's an extra owner positional argument given, which leads to this error. On a side note, I think `super().__init__(name, color)` works just as well too in Python 3

Answer (score 3):

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,gender):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender

class Salary:
    def __init__(self,name,gender):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender
    def jump(self):
        print(self.name,self.salary)

class Male(Salary,Employee):
    def __init__(self,name,gender,occupation):
        self.occupation=occupation
        super().__init__(name,gender)


employee1 = Male("Jim","male","technician")
print(employee1.name)
```

""" You were writing the occupation parameter in the super, but super calls to the parent class and your parent class does not have occupation parameter. The occupation belongs only to the Class Male."""

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee:
   def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

class Salary:
  def __init__(self, name, gender):
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender   
  def jump(self):
    print(self.name, self.salary)

class Male(Salary, Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, gender, occupation):
      self.occupation = occupation
      Employee.__init__(self, name, gender)
      Salary.__init__(self, name, gender)

employee1 = Male("Jim", "male", "technician")
print(employee1.name)
```

[Python - Inheritance](https://alphacodingskills.com/python/python-inheritance.php)

To access all the methods and properties of base class `Employee`, `super()` function is used in derived class `Male`. 
Syntax for using `super` function is shown in example. 
Along with this, use `print(employee1.name)` instead of `print(Male.name)`.

Comment: please add some text to clarify your answer

Comment: This will still fail, because `super().__init__` is going to try to call `Salary.__init__` first.

Comment: modified the answer to tackle `Salary.__init__`.